# Cómo obtener la URL de la página actual en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Cuando cargue una página, necesito obtener una palabra de la misma URL, por ejemplo

```
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15530/obtener-array-list-por-asynctask-de-una-url
```

Lo que quiero obtener es:

```
obtener-array-list-por-asynctask-de-una-url
```

Estoy programando en ASP. net C# para web

Comment: Realizar un split del contenido por "/" y quedarte con la última posición podría funcionar. También obtener el último indice de "/" y tomar el substring desde ese índice al final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Teniendo en cuenta** que la cadena que quieres obtener **no tendrá** `/` , puedes utilizar como separador la barra `/`, parseando el URL y separando el último resultado del `array` obtenido.

**Código:**

```
string cadena = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15530/obtener-array-list-por-asynctask-de-una-url';
string[] Separado = cadena.Split('/');
string Final = Separado[Separado.Length - 1];
```

EDIT:

Para obtener la **URL** de la página que estás, en ASP C#, puedes hacer uso de **`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`**.

El código final te quedará:

```
string cadena = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string[] Separado = cadena.Split('/');
string Final = Separado[Separado.Length - 1];
```

Comment: Me he permitido editar la respuesta ya que tenías un par de pequeños fallos. Por lo demas buena respuesta

Comment: @Pikoh ¡No hay problema! Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Me parece correcta la manera, pero lo que realmente necesito es que cada vez que cargue la página obtener ese URL para poder manipularlo como dices

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez perfecto, necesito entonces más información para ayudarte: ¿sobre qué estas trabajando? `win-forms`, con un control `webbrowser` o una página de `asp.NET`. **Modifica por favor tu pregunta**, y adaptamos la respuesta.

Comment: Listo, ya corregí, estoy usando asp.net

Comment: Muchas gracias Agustín, me funcionó

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener la URL actual puedes hacerlo desde la vista con la siguiente línea:

```
string _url = Request.Url.Query.Split('/');
```

Para obtener el último dato:

```
string[] _urlData = Request.Url.Query.Split('/');
string _last = _urlData.Last();
```

o bien

```
string _last = _urlData[_urlData.Length-1];
```

Comment: Tengo que importar alguna libreria para usar porque no me sale

Comment: Debería bastar con using System.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias